# Image load event not working on iPhones in Angular project

Tags: html, css, ios, browser, frontend

I'm encountering an issue with the img tag's load event in my Angular project. Specifically, the load event doesn't seem to trigger as expected on iPhones. I've implemented the event handling logic as follows:

```
<!-- My img tag -->
<img
    [ngClass]="{'set-lower-z-index': !service?.details || !service?.details?.Loaded}"
    class="item_image__fm"
    height="100%"
    width="100%"
    [alt]="service?.details?.Title || ''"
    (load)="handleSuccessLoad(service?.details)"
/>
```

In my Angular component, I have the following logic to handle the load event:

```
public handleSuccessLoad(promoItem: IPromoDetails | undefined): void {
    console.log('promoItem---1,', promoItem);
    if (promoItem) {
        console.log('promotem---2,', promoItem);
        promoItem.Loaded = true;
    }
}
```

This code works as expected on most browsers and devices, but on iPhones, the load event appears to be causing an infinite animation.

I've tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Checked for CSS issues that might affect the animation.
Ensured that images are properly optimized for web use.
Tested on different iPhone models and iOS versions, and the problem persists.
I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue specifically on iPhones. Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.